# Unable to use Azure Developer CLI (azd) in vsCode even after extensions installed

Tags: azure, vscode-extensions, azure-cli

I have been attempting to integrate and utilize Azure DevOps (AZD) within Visual Studio Code (VSCode) for my development work. Despite trying multiple methods and approaches, I have consistently encountered issues that prevent successful utilization.

The main problem is that every time I attempt to use AZD in VSCode, the operation fails. This issue persists regardless of the specific function or feature of AZD I'm trying to use. The failure does not seem to be tied to a specific action or command within the AZD extension.

I have followed several online tutorials and official documentation to set up and use AZD in VSCode, ensuring that all the necessary prerequisites and settings are correctly configured. Despite this, the problem remains unresolved.

1. Install the** Azure Developer CLI ** extension:
   [image]
2. Install the standalone Azure Developer CLI via the following command in vscode terminal.

`powershell -ex AllSigned -c "Invoke-RestMethod 'https://aka.ms/install-azd.ps1' | Invoke-Expression"`

```
VERBOSE: Downloading build from https://azure-dev.azureedge.net/azd/standalone/release/latest/azd-windows-amd64.msi
VERBOSE: Verifying signature of D:\Users\2303906\AppData\Local\Temp\4ofthncj.h02\azd-windows-amd64.msi
VERBOSE: Installing MSI
VERBOSE: Cleaning temporary install directory: D:\Users\2303906\AppData\Local\Temp\4ofthncj.h02
Successfully installed azd
Azure Developer CLI (azd) installed successfully. You may need to restart running programs for installation to take effect.
- For Windows Terminal, start a new Windows Terminal instance.
- For VSCode, close all instances of VSCode and then restart it.

The Azure Developer CLI collects usage data and sends that usage data to Microsoft in order to help us improve your experience.
You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the AZURE_DEV_COLLECT_TELEMETRY environment variable to 'no' in the shell you use.
```

But when I tried to verify, I still met the issue:

```
azd auth login

azd: The term 'azd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***When I tried to reproduce the same in my environment, I was getting the same error.***

[image]

**Steps I followed to install Azure Developer CLI:**

1. Installed Azure Developer CLI in visual studio code->Extensions:

[image]

[image]

To fix the error:

> `The term azd is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet`

Install `az` module by running the below command:
`Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force`

[image]

***Now, able to login to azd:***

[image]

***Initialized a new project:***

[image]

**References:**
[Install Azure Developer CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/azure-developer-cli/overview)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem with installation with PowerShell with 'winget install microsoft.azd' command too.